# Does the planar vector field $f_1 \nabla f_2 - f_2 \nabla f_1$ have a name?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Doing basic geometry with a vector field in the plane, I encountered what looks like a basic object and wonder if it is a well-known concept, which would help me relate this to known literature.

Given a differentiable vector field $\boldsymbol{f}$ in the plane with coordinates $f_1 (x_1,x_2)$ and $f_2 (x_1,x_2)$, does the vector field  $\boldsymbol{g}$ defined as
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{g} (x_1,x_2) = f_1 (x_1,x_2) \nabla f_2 (x_1,x_2) - f_2 (x_1,x_2) \nabla f_1 (x_1,x_2)
\end{equation}
have a name? Can it be easily related to standard vector operators like the curl?

This object has interesting properties that quantify how "parallel" the field is locally. It is zero when all the vectors point in the same direction, independently of their variations in norm. Conversely, the direction $\boldsymbol{g}$ is pointing at what seems to be the direction of "maximal variation in direction" of $\boldsymbol{f}$.

Comment: @PtF It seems like $g$ is $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$

Comment: A gradient is a vector, i.e. $\nabla f_i \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, right? I'm not sure I see the problem.

Comment: @PtF The gradients are *not* mappings $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, but rather $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, so $g$ is indeed a vector field just as stated in the post.

Comment: @PtF
$$ \nabla f_i = \left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_2}  \right), $$
so explicitly
$$ g = f_1 \, \nabla f_2 - f_2 \, \nabla f_1 = \left( f_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} - f_2\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}, \; f_1\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} - f_2\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}  \right) $$

Comment: Sure, I don't know what I was thinking, sorry.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was thinking about the Laplacian $\Delta f$ (for function $f: \mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R$), that is why it wasn't making any sense..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this has no name. But here's why your last paragraph takes place. Notice that — provided $f_1\ne 0$ —
$$\vec g = f_1^2\, \nabla\left(\frac{f_2}{f_1}\right).$$
Thus, $\vec g = \vec 0$ when the function $f_2/f_1$ is constant, i.e., when the vector field $\vec f$ has constant slope. Thus, as usual with the gradient, $\vec g$ points in the direction in which the *slope* of $\vec f$ changes most rapidly, as your last observation suggests.